# data validation case sensitive string in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, data-validation

I'm trying to formulate a data validation code in Google Sheets for a simple 6-letter string - any 3 capital letters and any 3 lowercase letters. I believe I should be using the RegexMatch function. Here's what I tried:

`=RegexMatch("[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]\\[a-z][a-z][a-z]")`

But when I try to type `AAAaaa` in the cell it rejects it.

Answer (score 1):

The formula is invalid because it lacks a range reference. In addition, the regex has a superfluous backslash `\`.

To validate a range whose top-left cell is `A2`, use this rule:

```
=regexmatch(A2, "^[A-Z]{3}[a-z]{3}$")
```

The rule will match when the value in the cell starts with exactly three uppercase English letters, ends with exactly three lowercase English letters, and contains nothing else.

To match strings that *contain* three uppercase letters followed by three lowercase letters, and may contain other text as well, remove the `^` and `$`.

To learn the exact [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) syntax used by Google Sheets, see [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).